# Squared Error Relevance Area (SERA) implementation in Python as custom evaluation metric

Tags: python, machine-learning, metrics, loss-function, catboost

I'm facing an imbalanced regression problem and I've already tried several ways to solve this problem. Eventually I came a cross this new metric called SERA (Squared Error Relevance Area) as a custom scoring function for imbalanced regression as mentioned in this paper. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10994-020-05900-9

In order to calculate SERA you have to compute the relevance function phi, which is varied from 0 to 1 in small steps. For each value of relevance (phi) (e.g. 0.45) a subset of the training dataset is selected where the relevance is greater or equal to that value (e.g. 0.45). And for that selected training subset sum of squared errors is calculated i.e. sum(y_true - y_pred)**2 which is known as squared error relevance (SER). Then a plot us created for SER vs phi and area under the curve is calculated i.e. SERA.

Here is my implementation, inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71058327/scikit-learn-with-a-custom-scoring-function-using-a-feature) other question here in StackOverflow:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.integrate import simps
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

def calc_sera(y_true, y_pred,x_relevance=None):
    # creating a list from 0 to 1 with 0.001 interval
    start_range = 0
    end_range = 1
    interval_size = 0.001

    list_1 = [round(val * interval_size, 3) for val in range(1, 1000)]
    list_1.append(start_range)
    list_1.append(end_range)
    epsilon = sorted(list_1, key=lambda x: float(x))
    
    df = pd.concat([y_true,y_pred,x_relevance],axis=1,keys= ['true', 'pred', 'phi'])
    # Initiating lists to store relevance(phi) and squared-error relevance (ser)
    relevance = []
    ser = []

    # Converting the dataframe to a numpy array
    rel_arr = x_relevance
    # selecting a phi value
    for phi in epsilon:
        relevance.append(phi)
        error_squared_sum = 0
        error_squared_sum = sum((df[df.phi>=phi]['true'] - df[df.phi>=phi]['pred'])**2)
        ser.append(error_squared_sum)

    # squared-error relevance area (sera)
#     numerical integration using simps(y, x)

    sera = simps(ser, relevance)

    return sera

sera = make_scorer(calc_sera, x_relevance=X['relevance'], greater_is_better=False)
```

I implemented a simple GridSearch using this score as an evaluation metric to select the best model:

```
model = CatBoostRegressor(random_state=0)
cv = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 42)

parameters = {'depth': [6,8,10],'learning_rate' : [0.01, 0.05, 0.1],'iterations': [100,   200, 500,1000]}

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, 
               param_grid=parameters,
               scoring=sera, 
               verbose=0,cv=cv)

clf.fit(X=X.drop(columns=['relevance']),
      y=y,
      sample_weight=X['relevance'])

print("Best parameters:", clf.best_params_)
print("Lowest SERA: ", clf.best_score_)
```

I also added the relevance function as weights to the model so it could apply this weights in the learning task. However, what I am getting as output is this:

```
Best parameters: {'depth': 6, 'iterations': 100, 'learning_rate': 0.01}
Lowest SERA:  nan
```

Any clue on why SERA value is returning nan? Should I implement this another way?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get unexpected NaN scores in a grid search, you should set the parameter `error_score="raise"` to get an error traceback, and debug from there.

In this case I think I see the problem though: `sera` is defined with `x_relevance=X['relevance']`, which includes all the rows of `X`.  But in the search, you're cross-validating: each testing set has fewer rows, and those are what `sera` will be called on.  I can think of a couple of options; I haven't tested either, so let me know if something doesn't work.

## Use pandas index

In your `pd.concat`, just set `join="inner"`.  If `y_true` is a slice of the original pandas series (I think this is how `GridSearchCV` will pass it...), then the concatenation will join on those row indices, so keeping the whole of `X['relevance']` is fine: it will just drop the irrelevant rows.  `y_pred` may well be a numpy array, so you might need to set its index appropriately first?

## Keep relevance in `X`

Then your scorer can reference the `relevance` column directly from the sliced `X`.  For this, you will want to drop that column from the fitting data, which could be difficult to do for the training but not the testing set; however, CatBoost has an `ignored_features` parameter that I think ought to work.

Comment: None of this options worked for me...

Comment: @DanielAben-AtharBemerguy If you provide a minimal reproducible example (as an edit to the question), I can debug on my side. Otherwise, post the code you've used and the full error traceback, and I'll do what I can with that.